# Swig C to Python ImportError: undefined symbol

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

I am currently working on wrapping parts of of a server code, the decode and parse methods, in Swig to use these methods in the python server code I need for a project.

I am trying to wrap the method below in Swig and keep getting the error ImportError: ./_rmsgrcv.so: undefined symbol: TCPMsgRecv.

rmsgrcv.i

```
%module rmsgrcv

%include "rtypes.i" 
%include "rmsg.i"
%include "tcpmsg.i"

%{
    #include "rmsgrcv.h"
%}

typedef unsigned int size_t;

char RMsgRcvParseData(int sock,struct RMsgBlock *blk,
          unsigned char **store);
```

The method TCPMsgRecv located in tcpmsg.i is called multiple times throughout RMsgRcvParseData to create the variables RMsgBlock *blk and unsigned char **store.

Here is the current way I compile the code

```
swig -python rmsgrcv.i 
$ gcc -O2 -fPIC -c rmsgrcv.c 
$ gcc -O2 -fPIC -c rmsgrcv_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ 
$ gcc -shared rmsgrcv.o rmsgrcv_wrap.o -o _rmsgrcv.so
```

Comment: When you built the `rmsgrcv` Python extension did you link with the .so file containing the `TCPMsgRecv` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment above I was able to figure out what was wrong.

It turns out I was compiling my code incorrectly.

Here is the correct way to compile it, in this instance (run each line individually):

```
swig -python rmsgrcv.i

gcc -O2 -fPIC -c rmsgrcv.c

gcc -O2 -fPIC -c tcpmsg.c

gcc -O2 -fPIC -c rmsgrcv_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/

gcc -shared rmsgrcv.o rmsgrcv_wrap.o tcpmsg.o -o _rmsgrcv.so
```